# Why using @ inside \newcommand gives "Undefined control sequence" error?

Tags: macros, listings

I'm trying to create a command that temporarily changes the size of a `lstinline`, so that I can properly use it in a footnote. The following commands seem to work fine:

```
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle=\footnotesize}
\makeatother
```

However, if I try to add them on a `newcommand` and then use it:

```
\newcommand{\testcmm}{
    \makeatletter
    \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle=\footnotesize}
    \makeatother
}
\testcmm
```

I get the folowing error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\testcmm -> \makeatletter \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let \lst @basicstyle=n... \testcmm
```

I know that this error usually happens when the command is not defined, for example, whan you forget to add the library that contains it. In this case however, it only happens inside the `\newcommand`. Why?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\testcmm}{
    \makeatletter
    \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle=\footnotesize}
    \makeatother
}

\begin{document}
\testcmm
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\testcmm ->\makeatletter \lst
                              @AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let \lst @basicstyle=\f...
l.12 \testcmm
```

because TeX has absorbed the definition text when `\makeatletter` is *not* in force, so it has stored

```
\lst@AddToHook
```

as eleven tokens `\lst•@•A•d•d•T•o•H•o•o•k`.

You want instead that in the replacement text `@` is treated as a letter, so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testcmm}{%
    \lst@AddToHook{TextStyle}{\let\lst@basicstyle=\footnotesize}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\testcmm

\end{document}
```

Don't forget to protect endlines.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the answer! (and the tip about the endlines)